# Finding convergence region and various series expansion of $f(x)=\frac{1-\cos z}{z^2-3z+2}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, laurent-series

Help me find convergence region and various series expansion of $f(x)=\frac{1-\cos z}{z^2-3z+2}$ .

I set $1>|z|$ , $1<|z|<2$, $2<|z|$, but I couldn't divide that.... help..

Moreover to solve $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos z}{z^2-3z+2}\,dz$
, am I right to evaluate the residue at $z=1$ and at $z=2$?

Comment: Do you mean the domain? $f$ is defined for $z \neq 1,2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $0<|z|<1$, then $|z/2|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{z^2-3z+2}=\frac{1}{2(1-z)(1-z/2)}.$$
For $1<|z|<2$, then $|1/z|<1$ and $|z/2|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{z^3-3z+2}=-\frac{1}{2z(1-1/z)(1-z/2)}.$$
For $2<|z|$, then $|1/z|<1$ and $|2/z|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{z^3-3z+2}=\frac{1}{z^2(1-1/z)(1-2/z)}.$$

Comment: Thank you but $not z^3 but z^2$ I edited few minutes  ago''8(

Comment: @matthew Corrected. Note that the integral is not convergent. Is your statement correct?

Comment: maybe that question want me to use improper integral like transform infinity to R... statement is correct.

Comment: @matthew That improper integral is not convergent. Here residue are not useful.